# Remote Repository doesn't contain recent Commits

Tags: git, github, repository

I have a remote repository on GitHub with two branches for my website. A master and a dev branch. Locally, I have one repository with the “dev” branch checked out, and another repository with “master” checked out.

**Problem:** Although using `git commit -am "message"` and `git push origin dev` (or `git push origin master` respectively) works for both repositories, only the master branch on the remote repository changes.

These are the first few lines for `git log --oneline`:

```
$ git log --oneline
e111369 Minor changes to CSS
2bdd236 Deleted _land-nav.scss
0bda307 Reworked lang-nav, site-nav/CSS update
165de39 Added .nojekyll file
ffeb959 BIG BILINGUAL UPDATE

# ^ above commits aren't recognized.

d24fa3d Preparing for bilingual update
bbcb7a3 Adjusted nav__item padding #3
216213e Adjusted nav__item padding #2
8bfea5d Adjusted nav__item padding
```

**Question:** What steps do I need to follow to fix this issue? Also, what additional information may I provide to help you answering this question.

**Update:** Why am I using such an unusual setup?

My dev repository holds uncompiled Jekyll source. I can't just deploy this to GitHub, because GitHub Pages builds without Plugins. I need to build the site locally to use plugins. However I still want to keep both uncompiled and compiled code on GitHub.

I don't know how I could handle this from one local repository. It's a dirty workaround I guess.

Comment: What do you have set as the `origin` remote for the repo with `dev`? Do `git remote -v`. If it gives the path of the other local repo, then  you need to set its origin to the repo on GitHub, see [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22104228/456814).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might have cloned the repo with the `dev` branch from your other local repo, the one with the `master` branch. If that is the case, then the `dev` repo will have its `origin` set to the path of the local repo with `master`.

#### Changing `origin`:

What you want to do is to have the `origin` set to the remote repo on GitHub, not the other local repo. You can use these commands in the `dev` repo to fix that:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin <url-to-remote-repo>
```

You can also use the [`git remote set-url`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) command to change where the alias `origin` points to in your `dev` repo.

#### Alternative: `push` from `master` repo

Alternatively, if your `dev` repo has its `origin` set to your local `master` repo, then when you push from the `dev` repo, that means that it's been pushing its changes to the local `master` repo.  So you could just push both branches from the `master` repo like so:

```
git push origin master dev
```

#### Unusual setup

However, your setup of having a repo with `master` and another repo with `dev` is unusual, usually people have both branches in the same repo, which would avoid the problem that you're having, and make your workflows simpler in general.

Comment: Your answer sounds plausible. I've cloned from the local repo indeed. This is an unusual setup indeed. I update my question with my reasoning for using it that way. Thanks so far. I try your solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me solving my problem. It would be nice to hear your opinion to my _unusual setup_. I've updated my question with some information about it.

Comment: @kleinfreund make that into another question of its own, you should be able to get more help from other people too that way.

Comment: You're probably right, but it's more a general question and not related to a specific programming issue, thus being off-topic. I'll find a better solution first, then. ;)

Comment: @kleinfreund … that would probably be suitable for [programmers.se]. See also: [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6311/60357)